Why is SO(2) a maximal compact subgroup of SL(2,R)
This is not a homework problem. I'm reading about hyperbolic geometry, and came across this theorem by Cartan that says all Riemannian globally symmetric spaces of noncompact type are of the form $G/K$ with $G$-invariant metric. Here $G$ is a connected semisimple Lie group and $K$ is a mximal compact subgroup of $G$.
So my natural first reaction is $SL(2,\mathbb R)/ SO(2)$ being isometric to the hyperbolic 2-space. But I'm struggling to see that $SO(2)$ is a maximal compact subgroup.
Here is my approach: first I know that if $A \in SL(2,\mathbb R)$ lies in any compact subset, then its eigenvalues (over $\mathbb C$) has to have norm 1. Because we can apply polar decomposition to get $A = SP$, where $S$ is an isometry and $P$ is a positive operator, which is diagonal with respect to some orthonormal basis. Thus $A = SMDM^{-1}$, and $D = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$. So if $|\lambda| > 1$, then $(S^{-1}A)^n = MD^nM^{-1}$ will have exploding norm (viewed as a point in $\mathbb SL(2,\mathbb R) \subset R^4$) and thus leaves all compact set.
The next step I'm not too sure: the image of the unit circle under $A$ is an ellipse. If this ellipse is not the circle itself, there is some $v$ so that $Av$ points in the direction of major axis. Since $\det A = 1$ the ellipse has the same area as the unit circle, so it must be that $Av$ lies outside the unit circle (the minor axis direction gets squashed). Can I use this info to say that $A$ (or up to some conjugation of $A$) has eigenvalue greater than 1, or something that would lead to a contradiction?

This question on the mathematics stack exchange may be helpful as it is similar to your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069634/compact-subgroup-of-sl2-mathbbr, although I have some suggestions, I am not good at geometry, so I will not post them here in case of incorrectness. :)

Using polar decomposition is a good idea. Here is a proof that $\textrm{SO}(2)$ is maximal among compact subgroups of $\textrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$. Let $K$ be a compact group such that $\textrm{SO}(2)\subset K\subset \textrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and pick an element $M\in K$. We want to show that $M\in \textrm{SO}(2)$. By the Polar decomposition, $M=OP$ where $O$ is an isometry and $P$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix. With $$1=\det(M)=\det(O)\det(P)$$ and $\det(P)>0$ we conclude that $\det(O)=1$. In particular $O\in\textrm{SO}(2)$. Hence $P=O^{-1}M\in K$. By the spectral theorem, $P$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$. Since $P$ lies in a compact group, all its engenvalues have norm 1: otherwise there would be an eigenvector $v$ such that $P^nv$ goes $0$ or to infinity. Since $P$ is positive definite, all its eigenvalues are equal to 1. But a diagonalizable matrix that has only 1 as an eigenvalue is the identity matrix. Hence $P=I_2$ and $M\in \textrm{SO}(2)$. This concludes the proof.
Note that the proof shows more generally that $\textrm{SO}(n)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $\textrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ and that $\textrm{O}(n)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $\textrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. Using the complex version of the polar decomposition and of the spectral theorem, one shows similarly that $\textrm{SU}(n)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $\textrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and that $\textrm{U}(n)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $\textrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$.
